# Symfony2 - Array being overridden

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I have a slight problem with an Array.  I essentially declare an array

```
public function getAvailabilityData(){
    $alerts = $this->em->getRepository('NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlert')->getActiveAlertIds();

    $alertsArray = array();

    if (!$alerts) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Availability.');
    }

    foreach($alerts as $alert){
        $alertId = (int)$alert['id'];
        $alertsArray[$alertId] = array();

        $allAvailability = $this->em->getRepository('NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlertAvailability')->getAlertAvailability($alertId);

        foreach($allAvailability as $alertAvailability)
        {
            var_dump($alertAvailability);
            $dateString = $alertAvailability['lastUpdated'];
            $dateString = $dateString->format('d M Y H:00');

            // Create the second dimension of the array, using the alert pseudo as the key.
            if (empty($alerts[$alertId][$alertAvailability['alertPseudo']])) {
                $alertsArray[$alertId][$alertAvailability['alertPseudo']] = array();
            }

            // Create the third dimension of the array, using the flight number as the key.
            if (empty($alerts[$alertId][$alertAvailability['alertPseudo']][$alertAvailability['flightNumber']])) {
                $alertsArray[$alertId][$alertAvailability['alertPseudo']][$alertAvailability['flightNumber']] = array();
            }

            // Create the fourth dimension of the array, using the date string as the key.
            if (empty($alerts[$alertId][$alertAvailability['alertPseudo']][$alertAvailability['flightNumber']][$dateString])) {
                $alertsArray[$alertId][$alertAvailability['alertPseudo']][$alertAvailability['flightNumber']][$dateString] = array();
            }

            // Create the fifth dimension of the array, using the class letter as a key, and the availability value as the value.
            $alertsArray[$alertId][$alertAvailability['alertPseudo']][$alertAvailability['flightNumber']][$dateString][$alertAvailability['classLetter']] = $alertAvailability['availability'];
        }
    }

    var_dump($alertsArray);
    return $alertsArray;
}
```

Now that first var_dump shows me that all the data is there.  It comes out like so

```
array(5) { 
    ["availability"]=> string(1) "9" 
        ["lastUpdated"]=> object(DateTime)#378 (3) { 
            ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-02-22 14:28:58" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/London"
        } 
        ["classLetter"]=> string(1) "C" 
        ["alertPseudo"]=> string(3) "123" 
        ["flightNumber"]=> string(3) "VS7" 
} 

array(5) { 
    ["availability"]=> string(1) "9" 
        ["lastUpdated"]=> object(DateTime)#369 (3) { 
            ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-02-22 14:28:58" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/London" 
        } 
        ["classLetter"]=> string(1) "D" 
        ["alertPseudo"]=> string(3) "123" 
        ["flightNumber"]=> string(3) "VS7" 
} 

array(5) { 
    ["availability"]=> string(1) "9" 
        ["lastUpdated"]=> object(DateTime)#367 (3) { 
            ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-02-22 14:28:58" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/London" 
        } 
        ["classLetter"]=> string(1) "I" 
        ["alertPseudo"]=> string(3) "123" 
        ["flightNumber"]=> string(3) "VS7" 
}
```

Now where I am creating my array, it should create records for each "row" which is outputted above, in this case it should do 3.  However, if I output the array, I get

```
array(1) { 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
        ["123"]=> array(1) { 
            ["VS7"]=> array(1) { 
                ["22 Feb 2015 14:00"]=> array(1) { 
                    ["I"]=> string(1) "9" 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

So it is only creating the last Object from my var_dump, it looks like it is overriding the other 2.

Now this is exactly the same as my normal PHP version I have working, the only difference is that instead of a foreach loop I do

```
while ($aRow = $availabilitySql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

So why is my array creation above overriding each time?

Thanks

Comment: what `var_dump($alertAvailability);` says? ps.: maybe an object should be better for this kind of "data structure" than an array. Second: where is `$alertId` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question with the whole function.  The var_dump can be seen in my second code block.  The third code block is the correct data for 1 row, but it should be doing it for all 3.  This is why it is strange, it works in my old code so not sure why its not working here

Comment: What that var_dump correspond to?

Comment: I have added the var_dump into the question, its a var_dump of $alertAvailability.

Comment: Just as an update, if I add a var_dump after I create the fifth dimension, I can see all 3 bits of data being outputted.  So I think it is definately a case of it overriding.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see where $alertId is defined and how it should be changed for next rows. I think it's just not changing ao you use same row all the time.

Also you checking for if (empty($alerts[$alertId]... but array is called $alertsArray so I think you mean if (empty($alertsArray[$alertId]...

Comment: If you don't know such important thing, this shouldn't be an answer but a comment.